# WSDL to java code approach generating extra classes

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl

Initially I have used bottom-up approach (Code to WSDL) to generate a wsdl file using three classes.

Now using the generated wsdl file I am trying to create the code i.e. top down approach using eclipse and its creating lot of classes than what I have used initially to create a wsdl file. How do I get rid of unnecessary classes and get the original classes which I have written?

Comment: It wont be possible up-to my knowledge. `Top down` will create stub skeleton to achieve the request  responses. It is almost like a stub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will most likely never get the precise original code if you go with code -> generate WSDL from code (e.g. jax-ws) -> generate code from WSDL (e.g. wsimport)  and that is fine because WSDL-driven development and it's counterpart are two different approaches.

With WSDL-driven approach your specify your WSDL contract first and then usually would generate you server/client code from the contract.

With code-first approach you define the service and it's operations in Java and would usually rely on a framework to generate the final WSDL.